# How to find the GCD/HCF of three numbers in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, greatest-common-divisor

I need a code to find the common prime factors of three numbers in Python 3

Whenever I run it shows me the wrong HCF / GCD.

Comment: if you have problem with existing code -- can you show us so we can find out the bug?

Comment: Well this was my original program

Comment: My program is wayyyy to long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple.
Write a function, that calculates gcd/lcm of two numbers.
Then do something like this.

```
gcd(a,b,c) = gcd(a, gcd(b,c))

 >>> def gcd(a,b):
...     if b == 0:
...             return a
...     else:
...             return gcd(b, a%b)
... 
>>> gcd(3,5)
1
>>> gcd(10,5)
5
>>> gcd(10,15)
5
>>> gcd(5,gcd(10,15))
5
```

You can try by yourself, for lcm.

Comment: Or just use `math.gcd` (modern Python, C accelerate for max speed) or `fractions.gcd` (any Python, but potentially slower) since it's already written for you.

Comment: Yes, it can be used. You are right, there is no need to recreate the wheel, but here, it might help in clearifying doubt using a simple approach.